# sqlserver 2008 with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I have installed the vs2010 and now I am using the "SQLEXPRESS" for connecting to a database, but now I want to use the sqlserver 2008 directy not SQLEXPRESS; for more explanation:

The sql express has this connection string(for example):(and I dont want to use it!)

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\EHSAN\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hokm\hokm\App_Data\database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

But I want to use this command(for ex):

```
Server=localhost;Database=xxx;User " +"ID=xx;Password=xxxx;
```

And I dont know how should I make a database witch want this connection string!

Comment: You will need to install SQL 2008 either on your local machine or or a server if it doesn't already exist. Also, poor practice to include usernames and passwords in your question.

Comment: For the record those username and password credentials are going to exist in the edit history of this post forever and ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Server=yourservername;Database=yourdatabasename;UID=yourusername;Password=youruserpassword";
```

Comment: ok, but I don't know what is my username and password,should I install sql server 2008 or it has been installed with vs2010?

Comment: First, install Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express. Remember the server name, username, passwords etc. you are giving while installation. Download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1695.
Second, install Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express. This is for connect with server. Download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593. Third, connect with Management Studio.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to add connection string in ASP .NET is to add it to web.config. This way if you change your server name or something, you do not need to go and change the connection string in all the .cs files.

In your web.config you ll add

```
<connectionStrings>    
        <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="server=ServerName;database=DBName;User ID=UserName;Password=YourPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

To access the connection string from your C# code you ll use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

If you want to use Windows Authentication you ll change you conenction string to `connectionString="server=ServerName;database=DBName;Integrated Security=True;"`

Comment: thank you so much for your usefull answer,but if you notic ,I asked:"how should I make a database witch want this connection string" really  I don't know how to make a new connection or create new sql server database witch want this type of connection string!!!!!should I install somthing?

Comment: you would need to install SQL Server Management Studio. And then you connect to Sever .\SQLEXPRESS. Also, you would need to create a database by that name in the server.

Answer (score 2):

Put this at the top of your code:

```
using System.Web.Configruation;
```

Put this in Web.Config:

```
<connectionStrings >
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

and where you want to setup the connection variable:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString());
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Must installed sql server 2008 version and Try this

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database="";User ID=YourServerUserName;Password=Password;"
```